# ShellJSInternalError: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat

Tags: javascript, shell, mocking, mocha.js, stub

I'm trying to stub the shell command using Mocha, but it throws the following error
`ShellJSInternalError: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\TEMP'`.

The shell command that is being stubbed is `shell.exec(`git clone ${gitUrl}`, {cwd: MY_PATH})`

I tried `shellStub = sinon.stub(shell, "exec").callsFake(() => Promise.resolve("pass"));`
and `shellStub = sinon.stub(shell, "exec").returns("pass");`
Both of them giving same error.

is there any reason why this is happening?

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. What's `shell`?

Comment: const shell = require('shelljs')